# Quick way of splitting a mixed alphanum string into text and numeric parts?

Tags: c#, regex, string

Say I have a string such as

```
abc123def456
```

What's the best way to split the string into an array such as

```
["abc", "123", "def", "456"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boundary you look for can be described as "A position where a digit follows a non-digit, or where a non-digit follows a digit."

So:

```
string[] result = Regex.Split("abc123def456", @"(?<=\D)(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=\D)");
```

Use `[0-9]` and `[^0-9]`, respectively, if `\d` and `\D` are not specific enough.

Answer (score 4):

```
string input = "abc123def456";
Regex re = new Regex(@"\D+|\d+");
string[] result = re.Matches(input).OfType<Match>()
                    .Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
```

Comment: I'd go for this one, and if needed you could replace the `[a-z]+` with `\D+`.

Answer (score 3):

```
string[] result = Regex.Split("abc123def456", "([0-9]+)");
```

The above will use any sequence of numbers as the delimiter, though wrapping it in `()` says that we still would like to keep our delimiter in our returned array.

*Note:* In the example snippet we will get an empty element as the last entry of our array.

Comment: +1: Adds an empty value at end, but seems easier than my version

Comment: @RubensFarias Yeah, I went out to have a smoke and realized this the minute started getting cold - thanks for the comment though!

Comment: take a look on @Tomalak version =)

Answer (score 1):

Add space around digitals, then split it. So there is the solution.

```
Regex.Replace("abc123def456", @"(\d+)", @" \1 ").Split(' ');
```

I hope it works.

Comment: python? didn't you see the c# tag?

Comment: @nyarlathotep. Sorry, I don't have a `C#` compiler.

Comment: @RubensFarias The solution is equivalent to refp's. This is primarily about regex, after all.

Comment: @Tomalak sure, but isnt C#; for instance, when I answer Java questions with C# (much more similar languages), I also get "isnt java code" comments. Maybe this ways is better, but I get your point, ty

Answer (score -1):

You could convert the string to a char array and then loop through the characters. As long as the characters are of the same type (letter or number) keep adding them to a string. When the next character no longer is of the same type (or you've reached the end of the string), add the temporary string to the array and reset the temporary string to null.